# Simple password encryption - how do i do?

Tags: java, mysql, encryption, passwords

How do I make a simple password encryption to go into a database please? I need this to keep my job!

Basially I need the code to do something like:
**EDIT**

---

I have a MySQL Table called "Usernames" on my local PC.

It has the following columns:

- ID
- Username
- Password
- Account Type

This table is used to log into the application, and I am in need of a secure way of storing the password. Can anyone help?

Comment: You probably want your password hashed and not encrypted.

Comment: I thought that encrypt was stronger?

How come I need hash?

Comment: `insert insert into table where password = "";` -- that's not going to work very well for you.

Comment: what would you suggest? I'm new to this sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In future, I'd suggest you refrain from begging for answers without first showing some code you've tried.

That being said, I'll bite.

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class EncryptHelper
{
    public static String ehashAndSalt(String passedpass) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException
    {
        String passwordToHash = "password";
        String salt = getSalt();

        String securePassword = getSecurePassword(passwordToHash, salt);

        return securePassword;
    }

    private static String getSecurePassword(String passwordToHash, String salt)
    {
        String generatedPassword = null;
        try
        {
            // Create MessageDigest instance for MD5
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            //Add password bytes to digest
            md.update(salt.getBytes());
            //Get the hash's bytes
            byte[] bytes = md.digest(passwordToHash.getBytes());
            //This bytes[] has bytes in decimal format;
            //Convert it to hexadecimal format
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i=0; i< bytes.length ;i++)
            {
                sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
            }
            //Get complete hashed password in hex format
            generatedPassword = sb.toString();
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return generatedPassword;
    }

    //Add salt
    private static String getSalt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException
    {
        //Always use a SecureRandom generator
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");
        //Create array for salt
        byte[] salt = new byte[16];
        //Get a random salt
        sr.nextBytes(salt);
        //return salt
        return salt.toString();
    }
}
```

Here's a nice and simple helper class for a hash/salt function. Just be sure to use the same "salt" string created when the user was created for when you authenticate the user, otherwise the authentication will fail.

Where passwords are concerned, I find it safer to use a hash/salt function rather than encryption, as encryption can be broken with the correct public/private key.

You can find more information on Java's Native encryption [Here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#provider)

---

**EDIT**

As @james large pointed out, You should randomise the salt. I've amended the code to show this.

Source of the above example: [HowToDoInJava](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/22/how-to-generate-secure-password-hash-md5-sha-pbkdf2-bcrypt-examples/)

I would then suggest you pass the salt and encrypted password to the database when creating new users, and then getting a resultset containing the salt and password and feeding it into a similar method to `getSecurePassword()` and using the outcome of this as a validation.

I hope this helps!

**Edit - 2**

Insert another row into your table called "salt" (or whatever you like), and insert a new user with a PreparedStatement, like so:

```
PreparedStatement pstmnt  = connection.prepareStatement
("insert into Usernames(`ID`,`Username`,`Password`,`Account type`, `salt`) values (?,?,?,?,?,)");
pstmnt.setInt(1, id); //would ideally be auto-incremented
pstmnt.setString(2, user); //user String obtained by any means
pstmnt.setString(3, securePassword); //from the hash/salt example above
pstmnt.setString(4, accType); //whatever naming structure you have for account types
pstmnt.setString(5, salt); //from the above example also.
pstmnt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: `encryptThis` is a strange name for a method that does hashing.

Comment: It was only a 2-minute code write from an existing project I have. I'll change it to something more appropriate :3

Comment: The salt serves no purpose if it's the same for all users.  It's only meaningful if you make up a new, random salt string each time a user gives you a new password, and you save that users's salt along with the hashed result.

Comment: james, that's a very good point, I'll add that to the answer. completely forgot about that fact *facedesk*

Comment: Thanks so much! I don't know how you know this, but thank you!